# We're deleting stale AD accounts for a company but owner wants to see the network files of AD users before deciding which accts to delete

Tags: active-directory

We are deleting stale AD accounts for the companies we work for.

I contacted the owner of a particular company to help us determine which AD accounts we can delete. He said he'd first like to see what files the deletion candidates have stored on the network to help decide which accounts are OK to delete.

We have a domain admin account. Is there a way to access AD User files? Is there a PowerShell command (or GUI app) to list the files of each AD user in a clean/presentable format that we could present to the owner?

I think he's only really concerned with the contents of each user's **Home** directories (the directories containing the **Documents**, **Music** etc. folders) -- and not network shares or shared folders users may happen to have access to -- because the **Home** directories are the only directories risking deletion as a result of deleting their accounts, right?

Comment: Questions about the _technical steps to do something_, even if that specific thing relates in some way to security, belongs on other Stack Exchange sites.  For example, questions about password standards belong here, the details of hashing algorithms used to secure passwords belong on Crypto.SE, and which function to use to hash the passwords belong on StackOverflow.  In this case, this is a sysadmin question (and really asks very little about the security of looking at user roaming profiles).

Answer (score 1):

> We have a domain admin account. Is there a way to access AD User
>   files?

Yes. Take ownership of the files.

> Is there a PowerShell command (or GUI app) to list the files of each
>   AD user in a clean/presentable format that we could present to the
>   owner?

There are probably a bazillion ways to do this. Pick your preferred method/tool and then research how to do it with your preferred method/tool.

> the Home directories are the only directories risking deletion as a
>   result of deleting their accounts, right?

The users network folders won't be deleted when you delete the user accounts.

Comment: @velkoon and what is meant by preferred tool here is to use Powershell ;) it will definitely be quicker and more useful in future!

Comment: Thank you--That's interesting their Home directories wouldn't be deleted if their accounts are deleted. I'm looking for a centralized location of all Home directories of all AD Users so that I could print their files out (by iteratively going over them with PowerShell). When you log into a new computer on a domain, your Home directory--along with your documents you'd previously saved within it on other machines--most often map to that new computer. Those Home directories have to be getting pulled from somewhere on the network. Where on the network are all those Home directories stored?

Answer (score -1):

before I will try to answer let me share some doubts...

What is the reason to delete AD object, especially user object? I am afraid it is really not a good approach because of AD itself and related systems. Once the user exists there may be (and the most probably there is) several logs, files or any other objects in AD or on the other systems (even connected systems in case you are using AD as authentication backend). Related system could be also exchange / office 365.
Once you simply delete the object you are loosing integrity of the information. Next to it behind each object in AD there is SID (unique ID in the AD environment).

Once you delete the user and in the future create it again, technically it is not the same user but different one!
In general the best practise is just disable the user. The account is not possible to use and in case the user became valid again in the future you can just enable the account.

To your question. Unfortunately there is not "easy way" how to get this information. You should iterate over the filesystem (e.g. powershell script). Please note that in case you want really delete the user account you should also remove all related information like file permissions on other than owned files or you would see just simple SID instead of username so any future audit would be really mess.

Please think about just disabling the account. There is much more information then just "owned files". In case of any kind of audit the better is to have somewhere disabled user than unknown SID ;-).

Comment: Common practice at our company has been to disable accounts. They are now moving to permanent deletion instead. There are reports that look messy with a bunch of disabled accounts in AD, so management has asked us to find ways to get rid of (a.k.a. delete) disabled accounts, along with any other stale accounts.
What filepath would I need to iterate over to see file contents of all Users' Home folders? (You're right--The issue of file ownership and losing access to files on network shares with specified permissions could be messy)

Comment: Not all home directories have to be on the same location. There is parameter with each object ``Profile-Home Directory`` (ldap: homeDirectory) so you can use this attribute. In case this attribute is empty the mapping is done using logon scripts so there is second place you can find out this information... Nothing would be deleted (no files including home directory) with AD object deletion. Anyway think also about create some OU (even with specific permission / delegation) to move the object there. This way you would keep integrity and "hide not valid" objects (win-win scenario ;-) ).

Comment: ... in case all the mentioned source of information is not "valid" there can be also GPO enforcing some path mapping based on some condition - username, group membership etc... The "final state" is combination of several value processing... It mainly depends on the setting of the AD. It can be from simple to very complex. Without more information about AD setting it cannot be more specific - only hints can be provided... Good luck ;-) !